# Using Headroom JS to hide navbar on scroll and appear when needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use Headroom.js for my navigation bar, but I am having some difficulties getting it to work.

( Headroom JS should hide the header & nested nav when scrolling down but appear when needed )

Not to sure where I'm going wrong, as I am still a beginner using javascript so I apologise for being very brief.

My HTML is set up like this:

```
<!-- initially -->
<header class="headroom">

<!-- scrolling down -->
<header class="headroom headroom--unpinned">

<!-- scrolling up -->
<header class="headroom headroom--pinned">

<header id="header" class="header header--fixed hide-from-print" role="banner">
  <nav>   
  </nav>
</header>
</header>
</header>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.headroom {
transition: transform 200ms linear;}

.headroom--pinned {
transform: translateY(0%);}

.headroom--unpinned {
transform: translateY(-100%);}

header.headroom {position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;transition: all .2s ease-in-out; z-   index: 9999;}
header.headroom--unpinned {top: -75px;z-index: 9999;}
header.headroom--pinned {top: 0; z-index: 9999;}


nav{
margin:0;
padding:0px;
text-align:center;
background-color: #ffffff;
border-bottom: 2px solid #d5dbdb;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999;
clear: both;
top:0;
opacity: 0.9;}
```

JS - I have linked the headroom.js file and jQuery file in my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/headroom.js"></script>
```

I have also added some script to the bottom of my page:

```
<script>
(function() {
var header = document.querySelector("#header");
if(window.location.hash) {
  header.classList.add("slide--up");
}

  new Headroom(header, {
    tolerance: {
      down : 10,
      up : 20
    },
    offset : 205,
    classes: {
      initial: "slide",
      pinned: "slide--reset",
      unpinned: "slide--up"
    }
}).init();

}());
</script>
```

Im not sure exactly what I am doing wrong, any comments or feedback would be much appreciated (Y)
You can check out the source that I am trying to use (and follow) here -http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/

Comment: If anyone is struggling with choppy or jumpy animation on your `fixed` position elements in Chrome, add these to your CSS for the fixed items: `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);`

Comment: I used jQuery to animate the header height to avoid a choppy animation, works well when using flexboxes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for plugins, here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/wdDsk/)**</kbd>

```
<header class="default">


</header>
```

---

```
header {
  background: #444;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.default {
  top: 0;
}
.fixed {
  top: -80px;
}
```

---

```
<script>
  (function($) {
    var ost = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var cOst = $(this).scrollTop();

      if(cOst > 200 && cOst > ost) {
         $('header').addClass('fixed').removeClass('default');
      }
      else {
         $('header').addClass('default').removeClass('fixed');
      }

      ost = cOst;
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

***Note:** Put the script just before `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for this (Y) !! Just one problem, is there a way to put a marker on how many pixels down the page you have to scroll down before the JS changes the class. For example the nav bar disappears even at the top of the page if the page is accidentally scrolled down by a pixel - which leaves a space.

Comment: Yes, replace `if(cOst > ost) {` with `if(cOst > 200 && cOst > ost) {`, 200 means 200px, change that in whatever value you need.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! To have the navbar to re-appear (class fixed) when scrolled up by 100px would it be a matter of applying a similar line after the else statement ? @mdesdev

Comment: @mdesdev: sadly your solution is not working with IE11